# multi-column ListView onClickListener responds to a column in a row?

Tags: android

In Android ListView it has OnItemClickListener() which responds to a ROW I clicked.  But what if my ListView has multicolumn and I want to have an event that responds to a column in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getView(...) of your listadapter simply use setOnClickListener() on what makes up the columns in you list row - ie as the row was a normal layout outside the listview.

Comment: I actually call another activity in this event. So I passed "this" activity in listadapter in order to call new Intent(thisActivity, newActivity.class); and startActivity(intent); My question is Is there a better way to refer current activity in getView() ?